# Performance lose due to call a User Defined Function in another database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on a SQLServer 2012 instance that has the same User Defined Function at four different databases. I need to introduce a change at that function and that means I will have to duplicate my change four times.

The function has a reduced number of dependent objects at each database so I have thought to leave only the function in one database (let’s calle it Main database), modify the function and change the references to that function so that they point to the Main DB.

However, before doing it I have a concern: would it impact on the performance? The function is a Scalar value function that does no select, it only applies some logic on the received parameters.

Best regards,
Sergio

Comment: Are the databases all located on the same server?  If so then I would think performance would not be changed.  If they are located on across a network then there could be a performance hit.

Comment: Yes, the databases are located in the same server, thank you for your answer sniperd.

Comment: No problem.  I'll write up a little quick answer @Sergio Prats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases on the same physical server should be able to use UDFs on other databases without any performance problem.  Ideally try and use fully qualified names for your objects, that can help with execution plans and cache.  Like:

```
SELECT column1 FROM the_database.dbo.the_table
```

Plus it can help with troubleshooting if you are making cross db calls "table1 doesn't exist? It's right there! Oh, it's in the other database".

If you were to make calls across a network, that could impact performance.

Comment: Would differing database collations not cause an issue here?

Comment: I think it would be OK.  As always, it's best to just try and test.  There can be so many factors.

Comment: For me it's impacting calling select from a fn and calling that fn from different DB. When I wrote the select directly as here instead it's away faster. Don't know the reason. Different DBs on the same instance.